# Изменение свойства экземпляра класса из файла куда он был импортирован. Асинхронный код

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, импорт, asyncio

Из названия вы вряд ли что-то поняли, не знаю как это можно сформулировать лучше =). Постараюсь объяснить тут. Весь код максимально упрощён, реальные классы и методы заменены на более простые, большинство ненужного кода убрано, всё для максимального понимания сути. Представим, что есть 2 файла - `start.py` - запускает весь скрипт и `export.py`, откуда происходит импорт.

Файл start.py:

```
# python3.8
import asyncio
# импорт другого файла
import export


class Test:
    """ Выдуманный класс """

    def __init__(self, arg=0):
        # Выдуманный аргумент
        self.arg = arg

    # функция, которая просто печатает единственный аргумент класса раз в 3 секунды
    async def print_arg(self):
        while True:
            print(self.arg)
            await asyncio.sleep(3)


# Создание экземпляра класса
test = Test()


# Функция которая создаёт задачи и запускает их
async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(test.print_arg())
    # функция change_class_instance_arg() изменяет arg свойство экземпляра класса
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(export.change_class_instance_arg())
    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)


# Не знаю что тут объяснять :D
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Файл export.py:

```
import asyncio
# импортируем экземпляр класса
from start import test


# Функция, которая раз в 3 секунды прибавляет к свойству arg экземляра класса 1
async def change_class_instance_arg():
    while True:
        test.arg += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

**В чём проблема?** В консоль печатается всегда 0 и свойство экземпляра класса не изменяется, хотя вторая функция запущена, выполняется и она должна изменять это свойство. Если файлы объединить и поместить эту функцию в первый файл, то всё работает как должно, и каждый вывод в консоль увеличивается на 1.

**Почему по-моему мнению это происходит?** При импорте создаётся ещё один экземпляр класса и их становится 2. Один создаётся при запуске файла `start.py`, второй при импорте переменной из файла `start.py` в `export.py`

**Какие решения мне не подходят?**

1. Нельзя передавать экземпляр класса в качестве аргумента в функцию `change_class_instance_arg`, потому что на месте этой функции находится другая, которая импортируется из библиотеки и я не могу её изменить. Если вам интересно почему функция из библиотеки должна изменять свойства экземпляра моего класса читайте ниже
2. Не получится сохранять значение в переменные окружения, потому что в реальном коде свойством класса может быть экземпляр другого класса, который никак не сохранить в виде строки
3. Объединять файлы. Это очень много кода. Это плохое решение

**Почему функция из библиотеки изменяет свойства экземпляра моего класса?** Функция из библиотеки это обёртка для моего кода. Внутри этой обёртки находится мой код. (Это не декоратор). Из-за этой обёртки я не могу ничего передать в свою функцию, которая внутри обёртки, потому что эта обёртка ничего не принимает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Происходит примерно следующее

1. Модуль `start` начинает загружаться под именем `__main__`, это важно
2. На строчке `import export` его загрузка приостанавливается до полного исполнения кода модуля `export`
3. `from start import test` (у вас в коде опечатка) приостанавливает загрузку этого модуля, пока не будет загружен модуль `start` уже под именем `start`. То, что он уже загружен (хоть и не выполнен целиком) под именем `__main__` - не в счет
4. модуль `start` загружается уже игнорируя импорты, все эти модули уже зарегистрированы
5. в какой то момент в пространстве имен модуля `start` создается объект `test`
6. после загрузки кода модуля `start` (`if __name__ == '__main__'` не срабатывает) возвращаемся в модуль `export`
7. там связываем имя `test` с `start.test`, определяем функцию, возрвщаемся к загрузке `__main__`
8. в `__main__` помимо прочего создается новый экземпляр `test`, и запускается asyncio.run()

В результате `export.test` и `start.test` - один и тот же объект, а `__main__.test` - другой. И изменяем мы первый, а печатаем второй

---

Решение навскидку:

заменить

```
from start import test
```

на

```
import __main__
```

и

```
test.arg += 1
```

на

```
__main__.test.arg += 1
```

Comment: вся беда изза if __name__ == '__main__': ?

Comment: @Интик прочитайте все целиком и внимательно. Проблем много, и решение одной может привести к появлению другой. Основной проблемой можно назвать загрузку модуля `start` дважды под разными именами.